# Gnuplot with Errorbars and line of regression

Tags: gnuplot

I want to graph some values with errorbars but it somehow doesnt work. Can you help me please?

```
431.00E12   0.69    47.00E5
567.00E12   1.10    58.00E5
662.00E12   1.75    67.00E5
```

watched a lot of videos and tutorials and did exactly what they did but it doesnt work.. The part with Regression and so on worked fine but now I want those error bars horizontally. My textfile is in this order:

```
x-Value y-Value DeltaX
```

The DeltaX should be the Errorbar so the errorbar schould look like this: at point x, the errorbar has length from x+-DeltaX.

Could you please tell me the code that combines the regression line and the Errorbars?

```
plot "/Users/amar/Desktop/dgd.txt" using 1:2:3 with errorbars, f(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check `help xerrorbars`.
A delta x which is 8 orders of magnitude smaller than the x-value will be difficult to see as errorbar. Just to demonstrate `xerrorbars`, I changed it to a similar order of magnitude.

With the following code:

```
### xerrorbars
reset session

$Data <<EOD
431.00E12 0.69 47.00E12 
567.00E12 1.10 58.00E12
662.00E12 1.75 67.00E12
EOD
set key left

f(x) =  a*x + b
a = 1e-15   # some initial guesses
b = -1
set fit nolog brief
fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via a,b
plot $Data u 1:2:3 with xerrorbars pt 7 lc rgb "red", \
    f(x) title sprintf("f(x) = %g * x + %g",a,b)
### end of code
```

You'll get:

[image]